# ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In Google Sheets, when using ArrayFormula with AND formula, I don't get the results as it should be.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 |

In `C1` I put formula as: `=and(A1>5,B1>6)` then I get `True`. If in D1 I put formula as: `=ArrayFormula(and(A1:A>5,B1:B>6))` I get the results as `False`.

Here are my two questions:

1. Why is `ArrayFormula` not repeated for all cells in the column?
2. Why do I get `true` without `ArrayFormula` and `False` with `Arrayformula`?

Answer (score 133):

`AND` doesn't work that way with Array formulae because it `AND`s the whole array together in the top left cell, regardless of number of dimensions.

I.e. it checks if `"">""` which is `FALSE`, `AND`ed with anything it will return `FALSE` for the top left cell, that result is carried down.

You can use multiplication of truth values to create `AND`ing that works with `ARRAYFORMULA` like this:

```
=ArrayFormula((A1:A>1)*(B1:B>6) = 1)
```

The `OR` equivalent would obviously be

```
=ArrayFormula((A1:A>1)+(B1:B>6) > 0)
```

Comment: You can also use it the other way around, FALSE, blank and 0 are false, everything else is true. Lets you do shortcuts such as `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), <something>, ""))` :)

Comment: And for fun, XOR: `=ArrayFormula((A1:A>1)<>(B1:B>6))`

Comment: Note that the brackets are required around the condition; otherwise, the multiplication or addition takes precedence over the comparison operator.

Comment: Thank you.  Also, this behavior of AND within ARRAYFORMULA is a surprise, seems to violate the Principle of Least Astonishment.  BTW, NOT within ARRAYFORMULA does not behave this way?

Comment: `AND` is an aggregation function, `SUM` behaves similarly in that it aggregates the whole range. `NOT` is not an aggregation so is expected to do element by element. I reckon there may be multiple cases where people have different expectations of what the right behavior should be with different aggregating functions. Always making it apply on the whole range gives a simple rule of thumb that aggregation doesn't change in arrayformulas. (I may be missing some counterexample here)

Answer (score 9):

Take this formula for instance:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(G3:G),IF(AND( G3:G>=7.5,G3:G<=8),"Full Day",IF(AND(G3:G>8,G3:G<24) ,"Full Day+",IF(AND(G3<7.5,G3>=4),"Half Day",IF(G3<4,"Short Leave",)))),))
```

Since you use the ARRAYFORMULA function you should use * instead of the AND function.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(A3:A),IF((A3:A>=7.5)*(A3:A<=8),"Full Day",IF((A3:A>8)*(A3:A<24) ,"Full Day+",IF((A3<7.5)*(A3>=4),"Half Day",IF(A3<4,"Short Leave",)))),))
```

When using the `ARRAYFORMULA` function you should use `*` instead of the `AND` function and `+` instead of the `OR` function.

---

### Explanation

I don't recall an official site about this right now. In any case.

**Point 1**
Within an arrayformula, `AND` gives a single value. **Not** an array of `TRUE/FALSE`.

**Point 2**
You must also remember that **in "math language", `TRUE=1` and `FALSE=0`**

Meaning

```
+----------+--------+
| Formula  | Result |
+----------+--------+
| =TRUE+2  |      3 |
| =FALSE+2 |      2 |
+----------+--------+
```

As you can see one can interchange between boolean `TRUE/FALSE` and `1/0` numbers.

**Point 3**
About the [**AND**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301) function

> The AND function returns true if all the provided arguments are logically true and false if any of the provided arguments are logically false.

**Putting it all together**
In an arrayformula, instead of using `AND/OR` when making comparisons, we take advantage of the above information.

So, the *"multiplication"* `(A3:A>=7.5)*(A3:A<=8)` will return 1 (meaning `TRUE`) only if both sides return `TRUE`. All other conditions return 0 (meaning `FALSE`).
This is the exact behaviour of the `AND` function and does work in an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

About the [**OR**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306) function

> The `OR` function returns true if any of the provided arguments are logically true and false if all of the provided arguments are logically false.

The same logic is applied within the arrayformula, when using `+` *("addition")* instead of the `OR` function.

Answer (score 7):

`AND` doesn't go with an `Arrayformula`. However, there is an interesting way to use `AND` and `OR` operators without really using them.

While using `arrayformula`, in order to do an `AND` function you must multiply the 2 conditions, for example

```
=arrayformula(if((condition1)*(condition2), value if true, value if false))
```

Similarly using `OR` functions is identical EXCEPT instead of a "*" Symbol you would ADD the 2 conditions.

```
=arrayformula(if((condition1)+(condition2), value if true, value if false))
```

Answer (score 3):

> Why is ArrayFormula not repeated for all cells in the column?

As addressed in previous answers,

`AND`, `AND`s the whole array, without regarding dimensions. But, given the recent updates in spreadsheets, using `AND` respecting dimensions, is now possible. If you  want `AND`, by row, you can use  `BYROW`:

```
=BYROW(
  A2:B4, 
  LAMBDA(
    row,
    AND(INDEX(row,0,1)>5,INDEX(row,0,2)>6))
)
```

Here, `INDEX` is used to access the first column and second column of every row. If you don't want to use `INDEX`, Another alternative is `MAP` , which provides a `MAP` of every argument before `LAMBDA`:

```
=MAP(A2:A4, B2:B4, LAMBDA(a,b,AND(a>5,b>6)))
```

| A | B | MAP | BYROW |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 | TRUE | TRUE |
| 8 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE |
| 9 | 7 | TRUE | TRUE |

Comment: MAP is to me the most readable solution, and the most compliant with principle of least surprise.