# Average based on a condition using OR operator giving wrong results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find average of a column based on the values from other column with different array formulas :

Using boolean **+**

> `=AVERAGE(IF(($F$2:$F$390="A")+($F$2:$F$390="B"),$D$2:$D$390))`
>
> Result is 40 and it is **correct**

Using Curly brackets inside IF

> `=AVERAGE(IF($F$2:$F$390 = {"A","B"},$D$2:$D$390))`
>
> Result is 40 and it is **correct**

Using OR Operator

> `=AVERAGE(IF(OR($F$2:$F$390 = "A",$F$2:$F$390 = "B"),$D$2:$D$390))`
>
> Result is 37 and it is **wrong.**

Could anyone help me to find, what mistake in the 3rd method using OR operator is giving wrong result ??

***(PS : All are array formulas executed using Ctrl + Shift + Enter )***

Comment: Similar issue with AND - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets

Comment: Also - http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/04/logical-operations-in-array-formulas/