# How to create a Google Sheets AND formula that returns an array of TRUEs and FALSEs instead of a singular TRUE or FALSE?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So here's what I have been trying to do.

I have written Formula 1 in cell `A1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Data!A1:A7="Angie")
```

And Formula 2 in cell `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Data!B1:B7<1000)
```

These two formulas return the following output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 3 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 4 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 5 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 6 | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 7 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

I am trying to combine these two formulas into one using the `AND` function in Cell `C1` (column C is the expected output), but I'm having difficulty doing so.

Here is what I attempted:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(Data!A1:A7="Angie",Data!B1:B7<1000))
```

and also this:

```
=AND(ARRAYFORMULA(Data!A1:A7="Angie",Data!B1:B7<1000))
```

Both of them return a single `FALSE` value in cell `C1` as opposed to an array output like the ones in columns A and B. I need an array output as I would be using it in conjunction with another formula. I am sure I must be missing something very important, and having difficulty zeroing in on it. Could you please help me?

Comment: Find the answer [Why does the AND() condition/function doesn't work with ArrayFomula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64425306/1527780)

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Calculuswhiz! That did it!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip and your explanation @marikamitsos! Didn't know this constraint with the ARRAYFORMULA :-)

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` is not supported under `AF`. use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((Data!A1:A7="Angie")*(Data!B1:B7<1000))
```

Comment: Using `=ARRAYFORMULA((Data!A1:A7="Angie")*(Data!B1:B7<1000)=1)` worked better instead - as this one returned TRUEs and FALSEs instead of 1s and 0s.