# Google sheets array formula display a message if the number falls within a range

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Here is my formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(S2:S>=90%,'Task Performance Legend'!C2,IF(AND(S2:S<90%,S2:S>=80%),'Task Performance Legend'!C3,IF(AND(S2:S<80%,S2:S>=70%),'Task Performance Legend'!C4,IF(AND(S2:S<70%,S2:S>=60%),'Task Performance Legend'!C5,IF(S2:S<60%,'Task Performance Legend'!C6))))))`

What I am looking to do is display a message if the number falls within a range.  I receive an error, "function divide parameter 2 cannot be zero" if the percentage doesn't equal 100%:

[image: formula in action]
[image: message legend]

I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, you can

- change the values in column A to a sorted list containing percentages only:

[image]

- use a vlookup (with the last parameter set to true) to return the text in column C:

  =Arrayformula(if(len(S2:S), iferror(vlookup(S2:S, 'Task Performance Legend'!A:C, 3, 1)),))

More info on VLOOKUP:

- [VLOOKUP()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Not all functions are able to return mutiple results. This is the case of Boolean operators functions like `AND`.

To replace AND you might take advantage that  `FALSE` values are parsed as `0` and `TRUE` values are parsed as `1` in on additions and multiplications, so intestad of

```
AND(S2:S<90%,S2:S>=80%)
```

use

```
(S2:S<90%) + (S2:S>=80%)
```

Related

- [ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43710792/1595451)