# How To Use Boolean Logic With Strings To Replace Multiple Nested If Statements In a Google Sheets Formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, boolean-logic

I've just found about the very handy use of boolean logic to shorten/replace multiple Nested If Statement from this question (4th answer):

[Is there a way to shorten multiple if statements?](https://web.archive.org/web/20220102211840/https://pretagteam.com/question/is-there-a-way-to-shorten-multiple-if-statements)

With this given example as substitute for multiple nested IF statements:

**Multiple Nested IF Statements version:**

```
= IF(E3 = "red", 100, IF(E3 = "blue", 200, IF(E3 = "green", 300, IF(E3 = "orange", 400, 500))))
```

Vs

**Boolean Logic version:**

```
= (E3 = "red") * 100 + (E3 = "blue") * 200 + (E3 = "green") * 300 + (E3 = "orange") * 400 + (E3 = "purple") * 500
```

That works well when returning a number is intended.

If true, the following returns 100 or 200.

```
=(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) * 100 + (REGEXMATCH(B19,F40)) * 200
```

But I get `MULTIPLY` or `ADD` errors when trying to return strings.

For example, with the 2 strings "Time" in cell `F2` and "Test" in cell `F40`:

```
=(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) * F2 + (REGEXMATCH(B19,F40)) * F40
```

returns this error:

> Function MULTIPLY parameter 2 expects number values. But 'Test' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

```
=(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) & F2 + (REGEXMATCH(B19,F40)) & F40
```

returns this error:

> Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Test' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

```
=(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) & F2 & (REGEXMATCH(B19,F40)) & F40
```

returns:

> FALSETimeTRUETest

### My question:

Is there a way to use Boolean logic with strings? If possible as concise as the way with numbers?

What operator is available for strings if there are some?

Many thanks for your help and insights!

Comment: This one is related use with AND and OR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710932/10789707

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the boolean solution is working with `(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) * F2` when `F2` is a number is that the formula translates `TRUE|FALSE * F2`, and sheets automatically converts `TRUE|FALSE` to `1|0` respectively if it detects that what you are multiplying/adding is a number since it is supported.

When `F2` is a string, it doesn't support multiplying/adding a string and a number thus causes your issue.

What you can use is a simpler version of `IF` which doesn't need nesting, looks and functions like what you are doing. This is `IFS`.

#### Your formula:

```
=((REGEXMATCH(B19,F2)) * F2) + ((REGEXMATCH(B19,F40)) * F40)
```

#### Turns into:

```
=IFS(REGEXMATCH(B19,F2), F2, REGEXMATCH(B19,F40), F40)
```

The above solution can also be used on numbers as well.

#### Reference:

- [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks a lot Octavia for the useful explanation of the `TRUE|FALSE` conversion to `1|0` ! I didn't know about that Sheets background way to make it work with numbers. Thanks also for the `IFS` workaround suggestion. I was wondering if there was a way to use the boolean method to avoid the many more parenthesis (it feels so much simpler for example `=REGEXMATCH(B19,F2) * 100 + REGEXMATCH(B19,F40) * 200` to work!) and possibly also potential sequential order processing constraints with the `IFS` solution. I'll see if I can make it work for my use. Thanks again!

Comment: I've worked out an alternative by using a assigning a number value to each `F2` strings and then using a `VLOOKUP` to return the string when the number is returned by the `REGEXMATCH`. That works for my current use.

Comment: I have to note that any of your current formula can easily be converted to the proposed formula above. You just have to convert all `+` and `*` to `,` and then place it inside an `IFS` statement. Also, combining boolean method and strings may not be the best implementation for this specific issue. I might get it to work but it might introduce more characters like parenthesis, commas, etc. Sorry as I may not be able to provide the specific thing you ask. Other users might see this question later and chime in here with a better answer. Let's wait and see.

Comment: It would be great to have a kind of Boolean Logic background operation specific to strings (though I'm not sure if that would be possible). Instead of the multiplication operation, why not use some kind of string match function to return the string? For example, converting the `TRUE` to the 'string value' instead of `1`. Then instead of multiplying by `1`, simply checking that the 'string value' match itself and if it does returning it. That would make an added 'string specific' boolean match operator (something as concise as the +-/* ones would be great). Thanks again!