# Check match between two sheets in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to compare values from one sheet to another and see the comparison of this in a third one. Let me share some values:

Data sheet 1:

```
Institution name    Management  Radiology   Nuclear number  Pathology   Laboratorie Systemic    Pediatric   Radiotherapy    Surgery Palliative
Institute 1           Log in    Log in      Not Completed   Log in      Log in      Log in      Log in      Completed       Log in
Institute 2       Not Completed Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed   Log in  Log in      Log in     Not Completed  Completed Completed
Institute 3     Not Completed   Not Completed   Log in      Completed   Completed   Log in      Log in     Completed
```

Data sheet 2:

```
Institution name    Management  Radiology   Nuclear number  Pathology   Laboratorie Systemic    Pediatric   Radiotherapy    Surgery Palliative
Institute 1       Not Completed Not Completed   Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed       Not Completed   Completed   Not Completed
Institute 2       Not Completed Completed   Completed   Not Completed    Not Completed   Not Completed  Not Completed   Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed
Institute 3    Not Completed    Not Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed   Not Completed       Not Completed   Not Completed
```

As we see in a few ones they match completed but in the ones that do not match I want two things in the logic:

- If in sheet 2 appears "Completed" but in sheet 1 no, the result in the third one will be "Completed".
- If in the sheet is not appearing completed in the cell, the result will be the text in the corresponding cell from Sheet 1.

I have my [Google sheet Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9leyYX5eYQdLlbZZgS26Jh8Y9yXf2paeCnbxgUU4Ic/edit?usp=sharing) with the full data and the desirable result in the sheet "doublecheck". Help please

Comment: If your question is about Google Sheets, do not tag with Excel. They are two different products, with vastly different functionality and syntax. Tags have meaning and relevance here, and should not be misused. Please use only tags that actually apply to your post.

Comment: maybe I aint seeing the requirements clearly yet but your data sheet 1 tab (track) and desired result tab (doublecheck) seems exactly same. can you maybe highlight the desired result tab cells with a different color on where these 2 logics you were referring to is supposed to happen?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow the desired result is the full sheet of double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a formula like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
IF(
(((Track!B2:K20="Completed")*(submission!B2:K20="Completed"))=1)+(submission!B2:K20="Completed")>0;
"Completed";
Track!B2:K20))
```

For clarification on the logical expression please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43710932/9848968).

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1plTvflGtBptaCYt89BT3V-l6an4GTlesqX8Gg-Y52Xg/edit#gid=1977586529)

Comment: Actually this is the formula I was loking for, Thanks