# Testing if one date range is partially included in a second date range

Tags: google-sheets

| Range A |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 Jan 2023 | 31 Mar 2023 |

| Test Ranges |  | Expected Result: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Feb 2023 | 15 Feb 2023 | TRUE |
| 15 Mar 2023 | 30 Jun 2023 | TRUE |
| 15 Dec 2022 | 15 Jan 2023 | TRUE |
| 1 Jun 2023 | 30 Jun 2023 | FALSE |

I would like to know if any date in a test range is inside of a second date range (Range A)

Here is a test spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WO9PFeJ8YORmlE5GDcwiKiK-pbmak8Vw1EIurP7H32E/edit#gid=0

Comment: What your question? Note that the link isn't accessible.

Comment: Please share access to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try:

**Using simple AND() OR() conditions. Try the following:**

```
=OR(AND(A4>=$A$2,A4<=$B$2),AND(B4>=$A$2,B4<=$B$2))
```

However, this does not work with arrayformula so you have to drag it down manually to your range.

---

**Another formula using the same logic:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A4:A8>=$A$2)*(A4:A8<=$B$2)+(B4:B8>=$A$2)*(B4:B8<=$B$2)>0,"TRUE","FALSE"))
```

**Result:**
[image]

**References:**

- [Find if Date is Between Dates in Google Sheets](https://officewheel.com/if-date-is-between-dates-in-google-sheets/)
- [ArrayFormula and "AND" Formula in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following formula

```
=MAP(B33:B41,C33:C41,
LAMBDA(bbb,ccc,IF(bbb="","",
      IF(AND(OR($B$31<=bbb,$B$31<=ccc),OR(ccc<=$C$31,bbb<=$C$31))=TRUE,TRUE,FALSE))))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formula according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]